# ORA-1861: literal does not match format string

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

I've encountered a quite strange behavior of a procedure called from various environments. The procedure is implemented in Oracle environment.

```
function licence_update(p_licence ax_import_licence_vw%rowtype) return number;
```

When I run the statement from Oracle everything is allright:

```
declare l_res number := null; begin l_res := licence_update(p_licence); end;
```

But when the same procedure is called from MS SQL using OPENROWSET I get an error

> ORA-1861: literal does not match format string.

```
EXECUTE ('BEGIN licence_update(p_licence); END;') AT LinkedServer;
```

There is a date attribute in the view ax_import_licence_vw, that certainly cause the error. If I take out this attribute the procedure always finished successfully.

So, I guess it happens because of NLS_DATE_FORMAT that is set up differently when the procedure is called. I took a look at the log table and found out the following information about nls_date_formats:

```
from Oralce: DD.MM.RR
from MS SQL: YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS
```

What kind of converting operation should be done to that date attribute to get rid of this error?

Comment: Why do you want a oracle function to work properly for sql-server. Both database are different and it will not work.

Comment: Show us the code that does something with that date value.

Comment: How can you possibly pass a complete row of type `x_import_licence_vw` from SQL Server to Oracle?